# Hibernate deleting child rows in many to one bidirectional mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, cascade

Hi I have created employeeentity and employeedepartment entity,Here I have established the bidirectional mapping between these two entity's.Now problem is while updating I need to remove the all childs from the table and I need to save new data to that list,But here the list is not removing from the table my entity mapping is like this.

**In EmployeeDepartmentEntity**

```
 @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "employeeid")
        private EmployeeEntity employeeentity;


**In EmployeeEntity**


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employeeentity")
    @OrderBy("id")
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.remove})
    private List<EmployeeDeparment> empdep = new ArrayList<EmployeeDeparment>();
```

**I am doing like this**

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        EmployeeEntity editemployee = (EmployeeEntity) session.get(EmployeeEntity.class, 95);
        List<EmployeeDeparment> list = editemployee.getEmpdep();

        Iterator<EmployeeDeparment> ite = list.iterator();

        while (ite.hasNext()) {
            EmployeeDeparment value = ite.next();
            ite.remove();
        }
        session.saveOrUpdate(editemployee);
        session.beginTransaction().commit();
```

Update :

If I use only saveorupdate in the employeeEntity and If I am deleting like this

```
for(EmployeeDeparment deparment:list){
        session.delete(deparment);
        }
```

I am getting exception as.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations):
```

Comment: Could anyone help me out please.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    EmployeeEntity editemployee = (EmployeeEntity) session.get(EmployeeEntity.class, 95);
    List<EmployeeDeparment> list = editemployee.getEmpdep();

    Iterator<EmployeeDeparment> ite = list.iterator();

    while (ite.hasNext()) {
        EmployeeDeparment value = ite.next();
        session.delete(value)
    }
    session.saveOrUpdate(editemployee);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
```

Use this and remove @cascade

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employeeentity")
    @OrderBy("id")
    private List<EmployeeDeparment> empdep = new ArrayList<EmployeeDeparment>();
```

Comment: Exception like this:org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [com.treamis.entity.EmployeeDeparment#123]

Comment: Than i need to store the data individually right If i don't have the cascde

Comment: Could tell me whts the problem with that.

Answer (score -1):

Removing from the iterator is not the same as removing from the list the iterator is derived from. Iterated objects are detached.

Comment: It should be comment not answer.